# How to postion the pageblock with style tag

Tags: visualforce, pageblock, style

I have to place one of my the pageblock inside a panelgrid to the top. Now its in the center postion.
[image: issue]

I tried using Inspect Element at run time, to make it top and found out a way. Its 
position: relative; 
top: -211px ;

below are the screen shot
[image: view3]

But i am not sure, how to include in the code, as its contains Pageblock.

```
  <apex:pageBlock title="Parameters" mode="edit" id="criteria">
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function doSearch() {
          searchServer(
                 document.getElementById("MailingStreet").value,
                 document.getElementById("MailingCity").value,
                 document.getElementById("DonorStatus").options[document.getElementById("DonorStatus").selectedIndex].value
      );
      </script>
```

Pls, let me know, how to do this
Thanks
Reshmi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Elements Tab where you have applied the style, right click on the selected `<td>` and choose `Copy CSS Path`.

Now, in your visualforce page, right after your `<apex:page>` opening tag use this code:

```
<style type="text/css">              
        PASTE_YOUR_CSS_PATH_HERE { position: relative; top: -211px;}      
</style>
```

Let me know if this works. That's the best I can think of now. Maybe somebody will have a better solution.

Comment: Hi Miroslav , Sorry . Its not the desired result. The parameters Block and Map block should be on the same Level. After adding, Map comes below of parameter Block.

Comment: When you used Inspect Element to achieve the desired result, what did the CSS class looked like? What were the selectors of the CSS class?

Comment: Hi Miroslav , I just added the  screen shot to my question. Pls see it above.  When i clicked the corresponding <td class= "colstyle"> , the full block area has been selected.  Does this answer your query. Waiting for result. Thanks alot . Reshmi

Comment: @ReshmiSmiju Please see my edit. That's the best I can think off now.